I keep getting errors with functions, even though I am following learncpp.com's couse and even copying the code
So far, since I'm still only on Unit 2 in the course (https://www.learncpp.com/) I haven't really learned any types of functions other than int and void. Whenever I use int or void, I always get an error saying that I haven't declared the function yet. However, int main() always works and the error never occurs. Down below is an example:
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int multiply(int z, int w)
{
    return z * w;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << add(4, 5) << '\n'; // within add() x=4, y=5, so x+y=9
    std::cout << add(1 + 2, 3 * 4) << '\n'; // within add() x=3, y=12, so x+y=15

    int a{ 5 };
    std::cout << add(a, a) << '\n'; // evaluates (5 + 5)
 
    std::cout << add(1, multiply(2, 3)) << '\n'; // evaluates 1 + (2 * 3)
    std::cout << add(1, add(2, 3)) << '\n'; // evaluates 1 + (2 + 3)

    return 0;
}

The error I keep getting is on line 3 and line 8. It says:

error: no previous declaration for 'int add(int, int)'
[-Werror=missing-declarations]" and "error: no previous declaration
for 'int multiply(int, int)' [-Werror=missing-declarations]

As you can see, the int main() function isn't detected as an error, but all the other functions are.
Let's just say this, I've tried what every smart person would try: googling, YouTube, asking questions in the comments section, asking friends who program in C++, going back and reinstalling everything, etc. Nothing I have found has helped in the slightest bit, so I'm totally perplexed and really need help.

Cannot reproduce on gcc/clang/MSVC: see demo.

"get an error saying that I haven't declared the function yet..."  The program works. Maybe you're using gcc instead of g++? What command do you use to do you use to build your program?  good c++ book.

You are compiling with warnings enabled (that's a good thing), and treat warnings as errors (that's also a good thing, in my opinion).  You could put those functions in an anonymous namespace (namespace { ... } // anon).  Or put static in front of those functions.  Or provide declarations, before defining the functions.

Dupe: Warning: No Previous Declaration - C++

How do you build? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question, and add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Seems to be a warning, which you could suppress but you have elevated into an error. This is a consequence of the way you are compiling your code (which you haven't described) not of the code itself, which is correct.
